# R Organize data in a list

Tags: r

I have a data set that I'd like to organize into a list but am unsure of the most efficient way to do so.  It's a list of sales people and products sold:

```
  rowId       repNum       prodNum
   001         12006        335506883
   002         12008        152348345
   003         12055        993047386
   004         12006        294726636
   005         12069        110847537
   006         12006        335506883
   007         12006        152348345
   ...           ...           ...
```

I'd like to create a list where each element contains a vector of items that rep has sold, my initial idea was to use `tapply` but that needs a function to net by.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your `data.frame` is called `dataset`,

```
split(dataset, dataset$repNum)
```

will create a list with a component for each `repNum`

---

```
> split(dataset, dataset$repNum)
$`12006`
  rowId repNum   prodNum
1     1  12006 335506883
4     4  12006 294726636
6     6  12006 335506883
7     7  12006 152348345

$`12008`
  rowId repNum   prodNum
2     2  12008 152348345

$`12055`
  rowId repNum   prodNum
3     3  12055 993047386

$`12069`
  rowId repNum   prodNum
5     5  12069 110847537
```

---

As [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568813/r-organize-data-in-a-list/12568923#comment16932251_12568923) by [mrdwab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1270695/mrdwab), you can get "vector[s] of items that rep has sold" by splitting the `prodNum` like this:

```
> split(dataset$prodNum, dataset$repNum)
$`12006`
[1] 335506883 294726636 335506883 152348345

$`12008`
[1] 152348345

$`12055`
[1] 993047386

$`12069`
[1] 110847537
```

Comment: Or `split(dataset$prodNum, dataset$repNum)` if they want to drop the `data.frame`s and just retain the "vector[s] of items that rep has sold".

Answer (score 4):

Using `tapply()`, you can do it like this:

```
with(dataset, tapply(prodNum, repNum, FUN=function(X) X))
# $`12006`
# [1] 335506883 294726636 335506883 152348345
# 
# $`12008`
# [1] 152348345
# 
# $`12055`
# [1] 993047386
# 
# $`12069`
# [1] 110847537
```

Comment: I should use `with` more often.  This is equivalent: `with(dataset, split(prodNum, repNum))`.  But, with your code, you can drop the `function(X) X` part and just use `"("` like this `with(dataset, tapply(prodNum, repNum, '('))`

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: nice use of tapply().

Answer (score 0):

You could also use dlply from plyr:

```
require(plyr) ## install.packages("plyr") if you haven't already
dlply(dataset,"repNum",function(x) return(x$prodNum))
#$`12006`
#[1] 335506883 294726636 335506883 152348345
#
#$`12008`
#[1] 152348345
#
#$`12055`
#[1] 993047386
#
#$`12069`
#[1] 110847537
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the first part of the output, I only saw the `attr`s (which you appear to have omitted from the output you show).

Comment: Yup. I personally like the plyr family of operations because I find them particularly intuitive, even if they ad some more cumbersome operations